# Meaning of Business Intelligence

Tags: business-intelligence, collective-intelligence

The word "Intelligence" has two meanings:

**1**: the ability to learn, apply knowledge, or think abstractly.

**2**: **a**: information concerning an enemy or organization or group with the task of gathering such information. **b**: news or information of any kind.

In the term *Business Intelligence*, which one is the meaning of *Intelligence*? 1 or 2?

Are there any articles on web about this distinction?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question. However, *Business Intelligence* systems are systems that are able to gather information, process them by analyzing the patterns and at the end of the day, forecast.

Comment: That's why it should be directed to a site that is [proposed for Business Intelligence. Throw all your sample BI questions there.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way we use it (with Cognos BI) is in the second sense.

Business intelligence is the information about your organisation and Cognos BI is one way to gather and present that information in a way that's easily adaptable and useful.

Having moved from BIRT to Cognos last year, I have to admit that, despite the increased cost of the product, things are a lot easier to do. It always seemed to me that BIRT was very little "BI" and mostly "RT" :-)

Sorry to sound like an advertorial back there, I was just stating how we use the term.

Comment: Guys check out [this proposal for a dedicated Business Intelligence Q&A site right under Stackechange umbrella. Throw all your sample BI questions there.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)

Answer (score 0):

> Business intelligence (BI) refers to computer-based techniques used in spotting, digging-out, and analyzing business data, such as sales revenue by products and/or departments or associated costs and incomes

1. It is pretty clear to me that retrieve and analyze data is a way `to learn, apply knowledge, or think abstractly`.
2. Yes business is about competition. Competition is about fighting.

So IMHO, two are valid